# I want to create dependent pick list using salesforce... assist me?

Tags: salesforce

How to create a dependent pick list in sales force?
Requirement:If I click on Country option then state will be display and then if click state then city should be appear...later it should be save a contacts that particular city...Is there any possibilities is there using salesforce admin
Assist me I am new in sales force

Answer (score 0):

For your purposes you can use [Dependent Picklists functionality](https://help.salesforce.com/HTViewHelpDoc?id=fields_defining_field_dependencies.htm). Also look on [Dependent Picklist considerations](https://help.salesforce.com/apex/HTViewHelpDoc?id=fields_dependent_field_considerations.htm&language=nl) for understanding of limitations of such approach.